# When doing TDD, why should I do "just enough" to get a test passing?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

Looking at posts like [this](http://blog.extracheese.org/2009/11/how_i_started_tdd.html) and others, it seems that the correct way to do TDD is to write a test for a feature, get just that feature to pass, and then add another test and refactor as necessary until it passes, then repeat.

My question is: why is this approach used? I completely understand the write tests first idea, because it helps your design. But why wouldn't I create all tests for a specific function, and then implement that function all at once until all tests pass?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The approach comes from the Extreme Programming principal of You Aren't Going to Need It. If you actually write a single test and then the code that makes it pass then repeating that process you usually find that you write just enough to get things working. You don't invent new features that are not needed. You don't handle corner cases that don't exist.

Try an experiment. Write out the list of tests you think you need. Set it aside. Then go with the one test at a time approach. See if the lists differ and why. When I do that I almost always end up with fewer tests. I almost always find that I invented a case that I didn't need if I do it the all the tests first way.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it is about "thought burden."  If I have all of the possible behaviors to worry about at once, my brain is strained.  If I approach them one at a time, I can give full attention to solving the immediate problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this derives from the principle of "YAGNI" ("You're Ain't Gonna Need It")(*), which states that classes should be as simple as necessary, with no extra features.  Hence when you need a feature, you write a test for it, then you write the feature, then you stop.   If you wrote a number of tests first, clearly you would be merely speculating on what your API would need to be at some  point in the future.

(*)  I generally translate that as "You are too stupid to know what will be needed in the future", but that's another topic......

Answer (score 3):

imho it reduces the chance of over engineering the piece of code you are writing.

Its just easier to add unnecessary code when you are looking at different usage scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Dan North has suggested that there is no such thing as test-driven design because the design is not really driven out by testing -- that these unit tests only become tests once functionality is implemented, but during the design phase you are really designing by example.

This makes sense -- your tests are setting up a range of sample data and conditions with which the system under test is going to operate, and you drive out design based on these example scenarios.

Some of the other answers suggest that this is based on YAGNI. This is partly true.

Beyond that, though, there is the issue of complexity. As is often stated, programming is about managing complexity -- breaking things down into comprehensible units.

If you write 10 tests to cover cases where param1 is null, param2 is null, string1 is empty, int1 is negative, and the current day of the week is a weekend, and then go to implement that, you are having to juggle a lot of complexity at once. This opens up space to introduce bugs, and it becomes very difficult to sort out why tests are failing.

On the other hand, if you write the first test to cover an empty string1, you barely have to think about the implementation. Once the test is passing, you move on to a case where the current day is a weekend. You look at the existing code and it becomes obvious where the logic should go. You run tests and if the first test is now failing, you know that you broke it while implementing the day-of-the-week thing. I'd even recommend that you commit source between tests so that if you break something you can always revert to a passing state and try again.

Doing just a little at a time and then verifying that it works dramatically reduces the space for the introduction of defects, and when your tests fail after implementation you have changed so little code that it is very easy to identify the defect and correct it, because you know that the existing code was already working properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. You need to find a balance between writing all tests in the universe of possible tests, and the most likely user scenarios. One test is, IMHO, not enough, and I typically like to write 3 or 4 tests which represent the most common uses of the feature. I also like to write a best case test and a  worst case test as well.

Writing many tests helps you to anticipate and understand the potential use of your feature.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by a best/worst case test? I see the meaning in the real world, but I can't think of how it applies to TDD and unit testing.

Comment: You're right, the "best/worst case" testing is not really related to TDD, but just something I have found to be really useful in testing. The best case is use to ensure that there is no regression after making a change to fix a failed test.

Answer (score 1):

I believe TDD advocates writing one test at a time because it forces you to think in terms of the principle of doing ***the simplest thing that could possibly work*** at each step of development.

Answer (score 1):

I think the article you sent is exactly the answer. If you write all the tests first and all of the scenarios first, you will probably write your code to handle all of those scenarios at once and most of the time you probably end up with code that is fairly complex to handle all of these.

On the other hand, if you go one at a time, you will end up refactoring your existing code each time to end up with code probably as simple as it can be for all the scenarios.

Like in the case of the link you gave in your question, had they written all the tests first, I am pretty sure they would have not ended up with a simple if/else statement, but probably a fairly complex recursive piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the principle is simple. How practical it is to stick to is a separate question.

The reason is that if you are writing more code that what is needed to pass the current test you are writing code that is, by definition, untested. (It's nothing to do with YAGNI.)

If you write the next test to "catch up" with the production code then you've just written a test that you haven't seen fail. The test may be called "TestNextFeature" but it may as well `return true` for all the evidence you have on it.

TDD is all about making sure that all code - production and tests - is tested and that all those pesky "but I'm sure I wrote it right" bugs don't get into the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do as you suggest. Write several tests for a specific function, implement the function, and ensure that all of the tests for this function pass. This ensures that you understand the purpose and usage of the function separately from your implementation of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do a lot more implementation wise than what is tested by your unit tests, then your unit tests are likely not comprehensive enough.

I think part of that idea is to keep simplicity, keep to designed/planned features, and make sure that your tests are sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good answers above - YAGNI is the first answer that jumps to mind.

The other important thing about the 'just get the test passing' guideline though, is that TDD is actually a three stage process:

Red > Green > Refactor

Frequently revisiting the final part, the refactoring, is where a lot of the value of TDD is delivered in terms of cleaner code, better API design, and more confidence in the software.  You need to refactor in really small short blocks though lest the task become too big.

It is hard to get into this habit, but stick with it, as it's an oddly satisfying way to work once you get into the cycle.